# Code working in Dreamweaver cs6 but not in chrome/firefox.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This code is working in Dreamweaver default browser but not in chrome or firefox. It shows only blank page , without showing google.com.  Don't know why! May be the problem is with iFrame. But I have to show something other page in my page. Is there any workaround??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>booo yeah</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(window).width();
        $('iframe').width(width);
        $('iframe').height(height);
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:http://goo.gl/jTpB2g
On back there is dreamweaver with left side code and right side its default browser showing the working code. In front, there is chrome in which nothing is showing

Comment: What is not working in your code?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: It shows blank page without Iframe

Comment: google has some retrictions on iframe. try another domain it works http://jsbin.com/UJeHaqe/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open you console panel and you can see an error message says:

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Google search returns an `X-Frame-Options` header with `SAMEORIGIN`, that meas this page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

See more from [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

**Solutions:**

If you have access to the site, try set `X-Frame-Options` to `ALLOWALL` or simply remove this from http response.

If you are stuck at google, try **use Google Custom Search instead**, replace your url with this `http://www.google.com/custom`, which sends 'X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL ' which allows you to embed this site in your IFRAME.

Answer (score 3):

The website you are trying to display has security that prevents it from being used in `iframe`. for example `<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>` works fine. The problem is not with your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not displaying for security reasons.

**Same Origin Policy**

> The same origin policy prevents a document or script loaded from one origin from getting or setting properties of a document from another origin. This policy dates all the way back to Netscape Navigator 2.0.

Some websites do allow it but Google doesn't. Strange that it's ok with Dreamweaver doing it.

There are ways you can circumvent it (I can't say they'll be suitable for your problem though).

[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

As ajtrichards said, Google has restrictions due to **Same Origin Policy**.

Just try another domain you will see that your code works

[**jsbin.com/UJeHaqe/1/edit**](http://jsbin.com/UJeHaqe/1/edit)